# Non linear least square model for carbon decomposition model

Tags: r, regression, modeling, non-linear-regression, decomposition

I am trying to build a carbon decomposition model using the nonlinear least square method using the exponential function, but I am not aware of what to put in the initial values.

```r
model_equation <- function(t, Co, k) {
  Co * (1 - exp(-k * t))
}

fit <- nls(Cm ~ model_equation(time, Co, k),
           data = dat,
           start = list(Co = 1, k = 0.01))
```

I got an error:

```
Error in nls(Cm ~ model_equation(time, Co, k), data = dat, start = list(Co = 1,  : 
  singular gradient.
```

I also don't know what to put in the initial values.

Comment: try changing the start values.

Comment: R provides a self-starting model for this: `nls(Cm ~ SSasympOrig(time, Co, logk), data = dat)`, see `help("SSasympOrig")`.

Comment: Why did you use logk instead of K? I am just learning and so don't know much about it.

Comment: Read the help page. The model uses `k = exp(lrc)` and fits `lrc` to ensure that `k` is positive. That means the `lrc` parameter is log(k).